# How to send javascript editable FileList to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filelist

In this [documentaion](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) says that in Javascript we cann't edit FileList inside 'input' element, because it is readonly. So what are the alternatives to send some other javascript FileList, that i can edit, to server?

Comment: You are up against a problem where JavaScript's security model prevents easy access to the file system.  The browser, being an executable application, has such access, but JavaScript code isn't the browser's executable code --and, actually, the access to the file system is done through HTML code, not JavaScript: `<input type="file" />`.  Worse, in my experimentation it appears that there is no way to automatically trigger the popup window where you select a file (in theory the object's `click()` function should do that).  Still, IF you can trust the user, then a kind of Answer exists (below).

Comment: Thanks all, but I found the solution in other [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12503471/2650905).

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTML test-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>test-page</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<!--

var fileobj, file;
function init()
{ fileobj=document.getElementById('filepick');
  fileobj.focus();
  fileobj.click(); //SHOULD auto-trigger the file-select popup, but doesn't
  return;
}

function filed()
{ file = fileobj.files;
  //At this point we should have an array of "item" objects,
  // containing all the files in the directory.
  //You can write code to pluck whatever you want from the array,
  // and then send that list to the server.
  return;
}

 // -->
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<input id="filepick" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="filed();" /><br />
User: please click button and select all files in the relevant directory.  Thanks!
</body>
</html>
```