# how to update a multiple input's number of files length after adding files programatically via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I add files programmatically to my `<input multiple>` element, the length attribute is not modified. If I dig into ti it shows that the files are contained in the input element, but the length stays at zero. I tried manually setting it, but I think the length value is read-only. How can I get the length to update?

```
//add files to cleared input multiple element
for(i=0; i<newFileListLength; i++){
    document.getElementById('documentInput').files[i] = newListOfFiles[i];
}

// change file length value (DOESN'T WORK)
document.getElementById('documentInput').files.length = newFileListLength;
```

Comment: "add files programmaticaly".  Could you please share code that adds files programmaticaly without user selecting them manually?

Comment: Well, my code is allowing users to delete files individually when they upload them in bulk. So if a user uploads 4 files, they can just delete 1 of the files without having to re-select the 3 files they want. So, with javascript, I am taking the files already uploaded, storing them in a variable, clearing the <input multiple> then adding the remaining files with a loop. (I will add the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `.files` is a read only property, so attempts to overwrite it will not result in error, but will silently fail.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp

See also 
[How do I remove a file from the FileList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist)

Comment: Bummer :(. Out of curiosity, how/why am I able to add files then?

Comment: You can use the `FormData` object to upload files over ajax, and this actually does give you more control over file submissions, but the downside is that it is ajax, not a standard form submit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData