# Image Upload with preview and Delete option - Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code below that runs perfectly and uploads multiple images.

This is the html and jQuery code:

```
<div class="field" align="left">
            <span>
                <h3>Upload your images</h3>
                <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
            </span>
        </div>
```

The script is as below:

```
<style>
    input[type="file"] {

     display:block;
    }
    .imageThumb {
     max-height: 75px;
     border: 2px solid;
     margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
     padding: 1px;
     }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

     if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#files").on("change",function(e) {
            var files = e.target.files ,
            filesLength = files.length ;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength ; i++) {
                var f = files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    $("<img></img>",{
                        class : "imageThumb",
                        src : e.target.result,
                        title : file.name
                    }).insertAfter("#files");
               });
               fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
           }
      });
     } else { alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API") }
    });

    </script>
```

The code adds multiple images and shows previews of the images too. But now I want that when a user clicks on some button, lets say delete on every image uploaded, it should be removed. Not hidden.

Any help to this will be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend to try this one. http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

Comment: try out this jquery pluggin : https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try adding this : `.click(function(){$(this).remove();});`. It will remove the image by clicking it.

**EDIT** Improved version included.

**EDIT 2** Since people keep asking, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist) on manually deleting a file from a FileList (spoiler: it's not possible...).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
            "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
          
          // Old code here
          /*$("<img></img>", {
            class: "imageThumb",
            src: e.target.result,
            title: file.name + " | Click to remove"
          }).insertAfter("#files").click(function(){$(this).remove();});*/
          
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
}
.imageThumb {
  max-height: 75px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.remove {
  display: block;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.remove:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field" align="left">
  <h3>Upload your images</h3>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much....worked like charm....it solved my issue....thank you once again...

Comment: when i submit..it shows only one file...even i upload multiple... @PinkTurtle

Comment: What server side language are you using ? If PHP try writing `var_dump($_POST["files"])` or `var_dump($_GET["files"])` to inspect your var contents.

Comment: I tried...M using PHP with laravel...i found only one image data being received at the server side.

Comment: This will only remove the image preview and not the image selected!

Comment: @JijoNair Have you solved the problem? I need to do same thing and I use Laravel. When I submit only last selected file/ files submited. Even if I remove the files it is also submitted.Have you found any solution?

Comment: @IshaS yes it does remove the images that I dont want even after selecting and opting to remove them later. Can you please post your error here through your console?

Comment: @IshaS and try dd using laravel and find how many files have been submitted. and to remove the name from the label after removing an Image , you have to place a custom label. That would help you out

Comment: @JijoNair Thanks for the reply. I didn't get any error. Images display and remove work well. The problem is when I browse and select several images and remove one of them and submit. It is uploaded with removed image.

Comment: @JijoNair Other scenario is First I browse image then display it.Again I browse and select other image.Then display two images.When I submit it upload only one image.

Comment: @PinkTurtle Great work indeed. How to restrict it to just one image ? I want to upload only image not many. Thanks

Comment: @IsrarKhan Identify your image with an ID (like `myImg`) and use `$("#myImg").click(function(){$(this).remove();});`

Comment: @PinkTurtle Sir, you deserve a medal. Thank you so much!

Comment: The issue is the same image can upload multiple times. How could you avoid that ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle why same image is not uploading after delete it please reply.

Comment: @PinkTurtle Can somebody share full code of preview and removing image, not just hide image but remove?

Comment: @Milos can you find something for this issue. I am facing the same problem. when I click on the remove image from the preview, not from the actual input field.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for remove files values and file preview

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
        $('#files').val("");
      });`
```

Comment: this will remove all files not only the one that you try to remove !

Comment: the above code remove all selected file or images. not working.

Comment: how do we remove file from the input file filed?