# Adding and removing attachments(instead of replacing prevoius one) on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

Please look at below URL: https://codepen.io/Sandipaot123/pen/LLJdeY/

I am able to add and remove attachment for one file, next time onward it replacing the old file with new one. How can I add one more row each time on click of upload button, and able to remove it too.

```js
var fileInputTextDiv = document.getElementById('file_input_text_div');
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file_input_file');
var fileInputText = document.getElementById('file_input_text');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', changeInputText);

function changeInputText() {
  var str = fileInput.value;
  var i;
  if (str.lastIndexOf('\\')) {
    i = str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
  } else if (str.lastIndexOf('/')) {
    i = str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
  }
  fileInputText.value = str.slice(i, str.length);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    $("#file_input_file").val("");
    var fileInputText = document.getElementById('file_input_text');
    fileInputText.value = "";

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.file_input_div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
}

.file_input {
  float: left;
}

#file_input_text_div {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.content-grid {
  max-width: 550;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}

.mdl-cell {
  margin: 2;
}

.mdl-list {
  padding: 1px 3px;
}

.mdl-list__item {
  padding: 3px;
}

body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <ul class="mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item">
      <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action">
                <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--colored">
                    <i class="material-icons">file_upload</i>
                    <input id="file_input_file" class="none" type="file" />
                </label>
            </span>
      <div id="file_input_text_div" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield textfield-demo">
        <input class="file_input_text mdl-textfield__input" type="text" disabled readonly id="file_input_text" />
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="file_input_text"></label>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209887/2534646) customize as per your need hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to play with input's "files" property, for example:

```
var filesToUpload = [];
$("file_input_file").change(function(){
  let files = this.files;
  filesToUpload.push(files);
});
```

You can find more information about [FileLists here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). I'm just curious if it's possible to send these files to server indirectly from custom array (as `filesToUpload` above) instead of sending it directly from input. If yes - then problem is solved. You can then modify the view basing on `filesToUpload`'s content.