# multiple file upload with delete feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a multiple file upload with delete feature - something like this image:

[image]

I followed [this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WWNnV/638/). I am trying to remove the button with id attribute *uploadBtn* and use native browser file input (for the upload).

So far I have this code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload"  multiple="multiple"/>
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function(){
    $(this).parents('span').remove();

})

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {

    var filename = this.value;
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
    var files = $('#uploadBtn')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     $("#upload_prev").append('<span>'+'<div class="filenameupload">'+files[i].name+'</div>'+'<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
    }    
}
```

**CSS**

```
.filenameupload {
    width:98%;  
}

#upload_prev {
    border:thin solid #000;
    width: 65%;
    padding:0.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
}

#upload_prev span {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

But this can't list the file name with remove feature. what can I correct here?

Comment: you didn't copy correctly the example, just replace `$('#uploadFile').on('change'` by `$('#uploadBtn').on('change'`

Comment: @oliv37 I'm trying to remove this `uploadBtn` and use default upload file input

Comment: ok so replace this line `var files = $('#uploadBtn')[0].files;` by `var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;`

Comment: @oliv37 thats worked :)

Comment: @oliv37 once I removing the files one by one, its not changing how many files i selected in first place, can u suggest something when removing files how many files remaining

Comment: can you show us a jsfiddle because I don't really see what is the problem

Comment: @kez see my updated answer (about handling removed items)

Comment: @oliv37 this is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kezputha/nLpth3ta/3/ ,once I remove files , its not changing the how many files currently remaining

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set value for an input type="file", 
which is wrong & It breaks there.

You should create one input type="text" and play around that.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes here:

1. Wait until the DOM is loaded with [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) before adding event handlers.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
       //setup observers
   ```
2. Accept the [*change event*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) argument in the change handler, then use `event.target.files` instead of `$('#uploadBtn')[0].files;`. Read more about this in the [passing data](https://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data) section of [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

   ```
   $('#uploadFile').on('change', function(changeEvent) {
        var files = changeEvent.target.files;
   ```

See it in [this modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aXlhyPEo4IPK88oY6uCe?p=preview).

#### Edit:

You asked in comments about how to remove an item from the list ("*once I removing the files one by one, its not changing how many files i selected in first place, can u suggest something when removing files how many files remaining*")

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162319/1575353):

"*If you want to delete only several of the selected files: you can't. The [File API Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) you linked to contains a note:*"

> The `HTMLInputElement` interface [HTML5] has a **readonly** `FileList` attribute, […]
>   [emphasis mine]

So you could clear the entire list, but not an individual item.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(closeEvent) {
    $(this).parents('span').remove();
    var fileInput = $('#uploadFile')[0];

    //clear all selected files from the file input field
    fileInput.value = '';
}
```

Another option would be to start uploading files in the *change* event, and after each upload completes, add a hidden input with the id of the uploaded file that can be removed when the delete button is clicked.

Comment: I'm trying to remove this `uploadBtn` and use default upload file input

Comment: in your example once I remove files , its not changing the how many files currently remaining

Comment: Right - like I mentioned in the last paragraphs (under **Edit**), the filelist is read-only, so if you want to remove all files, then you can set the value to a blank value (e.g. blank string).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div class="row uploadwrapper">
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="file" class="document" name="document[]" accept="image/jpeg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">  
<button type="button" onclick="uploadanother(this)">+ Upload another document</button>
</div>
</div>

function uploadanother(elem)
{
var document    = $(elem).parent().prev().find('input[type="file"]').val();
if(document!='')
{
var clonewrap   = $(elem).parent().parent().clone();                
clonewrap.find('button').removeAttr('onclick');
clonewrap.find('button').attr('onclick','removeupload(this)');
clonewrap.find('button').html('- Remove document');
$(elem).parent().parent().before(clonewrap);
$(elem).parent().prev().find('input[type="file"]').val('');
}
}

function removeupload(elem)
{
$(elem).parent().parent().remove();
}
```