# Remove data from array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I'm creating file preview and delete functions in jQuery but when i delete preview element its should also delete array.

**Html**

```
 <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        <input multiple type="file" id="ImageBrowsers" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="Gallary">

    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ImageBrowsers").change(function () {
            var File = this.files;
            for (var i in File) {
                if (typeof File[i] == 'object') {
                    ImageReader(File[i]);
                }                
            }
        });
    });
    // Image Preview Function 
    function ImageReader(File) {        
        var Reader = new FileReader;
        var Img = new Image;        
        Reader.readAsDataURL(File);
        Reader.onload = function (_File) {
            Img.src = _File.target.result;
            Img.onload = function () {
                var Height = this.height;
                var Width = this.width;
                var Type = File.type;
                var Size = File.size;
                console.log(File.name);
                $("#Gallary").append('<div class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + (_File.target.result) + '"/><div class="caption"><a href="#" onclick="ClearPreview(this,\'' +  File.name + '\')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a><p> Size: ' + (Size) + ',' + (Height) + 'x' + (Width) + ', Type: ' + (Type) +'</p></div></div>')                
                $("#Description").text();
            }
        }
    }

    function ClearPreview(Element, FileName) {
        var Name = FileName;
        $(Element).parents('div.thumbnail').remove();
        var Images = $("#ImageBrowsers")[0].files;

        for (var x in Images) {
            if (FileName == Images[x].name) {
                Images[x].remove();
            }
        }
```

i know remove function will not remove array but i have tried splice maybe i'm doing something wrong please help me to update file array as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct way to remove an element from an array:

```
Images.slice(x, 1);
```

But this would mess up the indexes in the array while the for loop is still running, so you could do something like this:

```
var indexesForDeletion = [];
for (var x in Images) {
    if (FileName == Images[x].name) {
        Images[x].remove();
        indexesForDeletion.push(x);
    }
}

indexesForDeletion.forEach(function(index){
    Images.slice(index, 1);
});
indexesForDeletion = [];
```

Comment: is Images an array?

Comment: i want to remove an array from multidimensional array

Comment: could you create a fiddle please? Hard to tell what the problem might be

Comment: ok.. So Images isn't an array. It is FileList, which is a readonly attribute and so it is not possible to remove only some files from it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162319/4887159 You'd have to use another strategy...