# Remove Specific File From File Array When Preview Image Is Deleted

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, file, form-submit

**Context**

1. In the simple form shown a `file` input element allows for multiple file uploads.
2. An image preview is generated for each file.
3. When an image is clicked on, this preview image is deleted (for simplicity I haven't included a delete button, it is deleted when you click the image).

On a side note the image files are submitted via PHP in the backend and the backend code all works as expected.

When a number of files are attached via the files input element it creates an array which you can see via the `console.log([...chooseFiles.files]);` line of code, which shows details of the files attached.

**Problem**

Can someone explain how when an image is clicked (and thus removed/ deleted visually) how you also remove that *specific* image from the chooseFiles.files array?

At the moment, because the image is only visually removed, the related image file is still submitted with the form.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/xxjQwLY

```js
let chooseFiles = document.getElementById("choose-files");
let previewWrapper = document.getElementById("preview-wrapper");

chooseFiles.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  [...chooseFiles.files].forEach(showFiles);
  console.log([...chooseFiles.files]);
});

function showFiles(file) {
  let previewImage = new Image();

  previewImage.classList.add("img");
  previewImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  previewWrapper.append(previewImage); // append preview image

  // -- remove the image preview visually
  document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach((i) => {
    i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.target.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

```css
form {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

input,
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input id="choose-files" type="file" name="choose-files[]" multiple>
  <button name="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  <div id="preview-wrapper"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: For one thing, posting directly to the db from the front seems like a bad idea, you gonna expose the connection string and password in the front end bundle, I even wonder if this is possible, sql connection is not through http. I also don’t quite understand the need for adding submitter to the mix, as far as I know submitter will refer to a button that was pressed (on submit button), why would you need an info like this ?

Comment: @LukeCelitan The data is being transferred to the database with PHP in the backend. Although this is mentioned in the linked question, it wasn't intially mentioned in this question which I have now added so there aren't any security issues on that front.

Comment: @pjk_ok I agree with the first comment too. I had to read the question more than twice to understand it. **just remove database part in your question altogether.** DB has nothing to do with it. it's just a form submission with files.

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: @sungryeol when I did that initially I immediately had an answer (subsequently deleted), and a comment (still there) saying I should never submit directly from the front end to a database for security reasons. Hence why I added that database reference in. But yes it's just a form submission with files but I can't get it to work and it's becoming hugely frustrating.,

Comment: @morganney - i've edited the question right down to the core issue and removed the excess code, which hopefully should make it easier to digest.

Comment: @pjk_ok Ok, I've added an approach you can take to only send the valid files to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare what is in the DOM in terms of the image previews and what is in the stored `FileList` from the `input`. Then only submit what is actually still in the DOM as a valid preview.

There is no way to remove an individual item from a `FileList` as you can see more of an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162319/258174).

- Add a `data-name` attribute to the image preview.
- Write a `submit` event handler for the form preventing the default behavior.
- Read the `data-name` from all the `.img` elements in the `submit` listener and compare them to the `FileList` while keeping only the ones with an associated `data-name`.

```js
let chooseFiles = document.getElementById("choose-files");
let previewWrapper = document.getElementById("preview-wrapper");
let form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault()

  const toSend = []
  const imgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img')].map(img => img.dataset.name);

  [...chooseFiles.files].forEach(file => {
    if (imgs.includes(file.name)) {
      toSend.push(file)
    }
  })

  console.log('sending', toSend);
})

chooseFiles.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  [...e.target.files].forEach(showFiles);
});

function showFiles(file) {
  let previewImage = new Image();

  previewImage.dataset.name = file.name;
  previewImage.classList.add("img");
  previewImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  previewWrapper.append(previewImage); // append preview image

  // -- remove the image preview visually
  document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach((i) => {
    i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.target.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

```css
form {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

input,
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
  <input id="choose-files" type="file" name="choose-files[]" multiple>
  <button name="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  <div id="preview-wrapper"></div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object to reset the `FileList` from the `input` each time a preview image is removed. This does a bit more work for each click to remove, but has the benefit of keeping the `FileList` in sync with the list of previews. It also uses the `FormData` in the submit handler so you can add other fields dynamically and post the data with `fetch`.

```js
let chooseFiles = document.getElementById("choose-files");
let previewWrapper = document.getElementById("preview-wrapper");
let form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const fd = new FormData();
 
  e.preventDefault();

  for (const file of chooseFiles.files) {
    fd.append('choose-files[]', file, file.name)
  }
  
  // You can POST this to the server with fetch like
  // fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: fd })
  console.log('submit', Array.from(fd.values()));
});
chooseFiles.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  [...e.target.files].forEach(showFiles);
});

function showFiles(file) {
  let previewImage = new Image();

  previewImage.dataset.name = file.name;
  previewImage.classList.add("img");
  previewImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  previewWrapper.append(previewImage); // append preview image

  // -- remove the image preview visually
  document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach((i) => {
    i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const transfer = new DataTransfer();
      const name = e.target.dataset.name;
 
      for (const file of chooseFiles.files) {
        if (file.name !== name) {
          transfer.items.add(file);
        }
      }

      chooseFiles.files = transfer.files;
      e.target.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

```css
form {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

input,
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form">
  <input id="choose-files" type="file" name="choose-files[]" multiple>
  <button name="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  <div id="preview-wrapper"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. i'm travelling at the moment so will go through in more detail later. I think the dataTransfer is going to be useful because the uploader is going to have drag and drop and a styled 'select files' button that uses this too. I took all of that out to reduce the code overload in the original question

Comment: @pjk_ok if this solution works for you can you accept the answer, or provide a reason why it does not work?

Comment: Like in the codesandbox this prints a message to the console but doesn't actually submit the images, which I think I'm going to need to do with `FormData()`, but which means I'm pretty much where I was with the original question before editing it all down. Although a very much appreciated and useful answer I'm now just facing a different issue.

Comment: @pjk_ok I've updated the last example by simply removing the `submit` handler for the form, so you can submit it natively using the second approach if you like. I think you just are not understanding what I've shown, or you're not asking the question you need answered, oh well.

Comment: can you revert the changes. I do need to use dataTransfer and FormData, I just need to wrap my head around a lot of new stuff. When the bounty expires I'll mark it as correct and if I get stuck with fetch()/formData  I will post a separate questoin. In fairness you did answer what I asked.

Comment: @pjk_ok it depends on what content type your backend expects from the frontend. You keep mentioning `FormData` which implies a content type of `multipart/form-data`, which is the same thing written in the HTML `<form>`'s `enctype` attribute, so either approach sends the same content type.

Comment: If you want or need to use `FormData` because you want to add other fields dynamically, you can use the `submit` handler to add the files from the `FileList` using the approach from the example on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#examples)

Comment: I need to use `FormData()` because I need to add a progress loading bar which I believe needs `JS fetch()` (or equivalent) to work. If I'm using `fetch()` then from what I understand I'll need to use `FormData()` to process the upload?

Comment: @pjk_ok I've updated the second example again but this time to use `FormData` in the submit handler.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, but I need to wrap my head around a lot of stuff and when I no doubt ask a second questoin on here with a future Issue I can see coming up I'll drop a link here if it gets to the 'bounty' stage. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @pjk_ok thanks, ping me if you do need some help with a second question.