# angular remove one of the file in FileList

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to remove one of the files in `FileList`, but I found that `FileList` is not an `Array`, and I cannot remove one of its elements through `splice`:

```
file: {
    files: FileList,
  }={
    files: {} as FileList
  }


 this.file.files.splice(index, 1);

// error message:
// Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'FileList'.
```

But through the for loop, you can see each file correctly:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.file.files.length; i++) {
      let file = this.file.files[i]; 
      console.log(file);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a file from the FileList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144419/how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-filelist)

Comment: @YongShun I have seen a discussion but it doesn't seem to solve my problem, he doesn't seem to be manipulating a `FileList`